# How to convert all numbers in a 2d numpy array to strings?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array of ints called M. I would like to convert all the ints to strings returning a 2d numpy array of the same shape. How can you do that?

I tried `map(str, M)` but that doesn't work as it converts the individual rows into strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to cast the array to particular type

```
m = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

m = m.astype(str)
m
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']], dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it right, you are trying to convert all integer elements in the array to a string. To do so, this should work:

```
np.char.mod('%d',M)
```